# C# IQueryable not working

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq, iqueryable

I have a `findAll` function that gets all the records from a `Contacts` table in the Database and then filters them depending on which values the user selected in the search form. The results are filtered one filter at the time.

```
IQueryable<Contact> resultContacts = db.Contacts;

if(request['Name'] != "")
{
   resultContacts = resultContacts.Where(a => a.Name.Contains(Name));
}

if(request['Phone'] != "")
{
   resultContacts = resultContacts.Where(a => a.Phone.Equals(Phone));
}

if(request['Company'] != "")
{
   resultContacts = resultContacts.Where(a => a.Company.Contains(Company));
}

return resultContacts;
```

The problem is that now this is not working. The `resultContacts.Where` inside each `if` is resetting to the original `resultContacts` I had on the first line for some reason. For instance: when I debug, the changes apply inside the 1st if (I end up with 10 out of 100 records), but when I go into the 2nd if, the code is querying the original `resultContacts`, not the 10 I had as a result of the first `if`.

This worked fine for over a year until 2 weeks ago. I don't know if something changed on my code... if I added a reference or something that make this change.

Any idea why?
Thank you!

Comment: Did you mean to use the request object in each query? Like `.Contains(request['Name']));`

Comment: I am amazed C# allowing this syntax `request['Phone']` single quote embrace `char` not `string`

Comment: Also, `request['Name']` is not the same thing as `Name`. Ditto for `Phone` and `Company`. Don't put code that somewhat sort of looks like what you have. Post *real* code.

Comment: I'm actually passing the request variables into string vars. I just used the 'Request' object in the example trying to make it clear.

Answer (score -2):

```
var results = db.Contacts
    .Where(a => request["Company"] == String.Empty || a.Company.Contains(Company))
    .And(a => request["Phone"] == String.Empty || a.Phone.Equals(Phone))
    .And(a => request["Name"] == String.Empty || a.Name.Contains(Name)));
```

Comment: you could just unify all 3 conditions into the Where clause right? this appears to work, just wanna be sure I understand it.

Comment: Yes I guess you could.

Comment: Give some explanation to your answer, not just some code. I don't understand the difference in behaviors between OP code and this one. To me they should work in the same way...